# .cpp:23: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int atoi(const char*)’

Tags: c++, string

Here a basic code I'm trying to run But I'm having trouble with stoi (it's c++) I keep getting error:

```
‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
```

I tried atoi and strtol with this error

```
.cpp:23: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int atoi(const char*)’
```

The code:

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string numberGuessed;
    int intNumberGuessed = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Guess a numeber btw 1 - 10: " << endl;
        getline(cin, numberGuessed);
        intNumberGuessed = atoi(numberGuessed);
        cout << intNumberGuessed << endl;
    } while(intNumberGuessed != 4);
    cout<< "you win" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use e.g. `atoi(numberGuessed.c_str());`.

Comment: `std::stoi` requires you to `#include <string>`, but it also requires a modern (C++11 compatible) compiler -- see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol. `atoi` requires a c-string which you can obtain with `numberGuessed.c_str()`

Comment: Just use intNumberGuessed = atoi(numberGuessed.data()); and you are good to go.

Comment: note: The original MinGW doesn't have `stoi` or `to_string`, however MinGW-w64 does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stoi`, it's the modern C++ version of C's `atoi`.

---

**Update**:

Since the original answer text above the question was amended with the following error message:

> ```
> ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
> ```

Assuming this error was produced by g++ (which uses that wording), this can have two different causes:

- Using a non-conforming variant of g++ that doesn't provide `std::stoi`.
- Using g++ in C++03 mode (`stoi` was introduced in C++11).

For Windows, the MinGW-w64 variant is known to provide `std::stoi`, and in particular the Nuwen distribution is based on MinGW-w64.

For C++11 mode, with g++ use the option `-std=c++11`. For example, this is necessary with the Nuwen distribution g++ version 5.1.

Comment: Than you so much for all of your help! I tried using "g++ -std=c++11 myprogram.cpp" but came up with command "-std=c++11" not found.... I'm using terminal on OSX 10.6.8 with xcode 4.2 which is probably why... The "intNumberGuessed = atoi(numberGuessed.c_str());" fixed it. I'll use that format from now on! Thank you so much for all of your help! You guys are incredible!

Answer (score 7):

The `atoi()` function accepts `const char*` argument, but you're trying to pass it `std::string`. Write it like `intNumberGuessed = atoi(numberGuessed.c_str());` to take the pointer.

As for the first error, about `stoi()` being undeclared — it is because the function was added in C++11 standard, so you have to enable its support in your compiler. I.e. in older versions of GCC you could do it with `-std=c++11` option *([since gcc5 C11 is](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) enabled by default, and since gcc6 [C++11 will be enabled](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC-6-CPP-11-Proposal) by default)*.

Comment: Re " (since gcc5 C11 is enabled by default, and since gcc6 C++11 will be enabled by default)", that depends on the distribution. With Nuwen C++11 was the default for one 4.x version, then it reverted to C++03 as default, and is still as C++03 with version 5.1.